# Unable to parse JSON file format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON in a text file which I am trying to parse.

```
{
"0":[68],
"1":[154,78,61],
"2":[89,132,146],
"3":[],
"4":[77,132,146],
"5":[32,132,50],
"6":[],
"7":[114,118,54,44,72,136,156,134,129,82,43,34,51,93,142,67,47,153,160,73,39,149,107,94,145,29,115,53,83,1,35,56,123,66,90,121,155],
"8":[89,146],
"9":[89,146],
"10":[100,135],
"11":[],
"12":[],
"13",[111,131],
"14":[77,124],
"15":[89,146],
"16":[163,126,122],
"17":[100,126,135],
"18":[32,50],
"19":[163,126,122]
}
```

The code I have is

```
 var map = new List<Dictionary<int, List<int>>>();
            using (var r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Development\phase2\dependencymap.json"))
            {
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                map = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<int, List<int>>>>(json);
            }
```

But it doesn't seem to like the format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to use `List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>` ? (string as dict keys vs int)

Comment: jsonlint.com is pretty handy for checking that you have valid JSON...

Comment: I suspect you are getting down votes partly because you're not telling us what the error message is. Also you do say "it doesn't seem to like the format", but if you just inspected the format or ran it through a validator then you would see it's not valid Json, so you're asking the community to do for you, what should be an obvious first step.

Comment: Aside from the malformed JSON, Your JSON is a single object, not an array. So you need to deserialize it into a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` not a LIST of dictionary (`List<Dictionary<int, List<int>>>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON is malformed. Check the following line

```
"13" , [111,131],
```

and change it to:

```
"13" : [111,131],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `map = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<String, List<int>>>>(json);`

Your keys are String, not int.